# Querying changed child property from db of a complex object

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core

I'm developing a chatbot where I ask a question that is not mandatory. if the client does not respond after 3 minutes I move on to the next question.

for this I have the following code:

```
Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
await SendText(id, "Whats your social security number?");
Thread.Sleep(180000) // pause for 3 minutes to check if the client answered
string _ssn = db.Clients.Find(id).SSN;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ssn))
{
await SendText(id, "Whats your ZipCode?");
}
```

if the client answers - then the property `SSN` is being updated in the database  and the conversation continues in a new thread. when the `Thread.Sleep(180000)` reaches on the old thread the if statment for the `SSN` property should be false and therefor should not send another text.

In parctice - it goes into the if statement where it should not and send the text which is duplicated with the text that was sent after the client responded with their SSN.

I thought that since I query the specific property (i.e `Client.SSN` and not the `Client` object from the DB) there should be no issues with reference types / pointers so I will get the actual value from the DB.

I will appriciate if someone can shed some light on this odd beheviour.

Thanks

Comment: `DbSet<T>.Find` uses caching. If you want to reload, you'd have to call something like `db.Clients.Entry(client).ReloadAsync()`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWilliamson I just amended my code with 'db.Entry(client).Reload()' I will update later on to see if this resolved the issue.

Comment: Please look into asynchronous programming with the `async` and `await` keywords. Using the synchronous methods offered by EF is detrimental to performance. They are there for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson your comment resolved my issue. thank you!